# Opening div on selection of radio with picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The first 3 options in the slider are working correctly, but the others aren't working. The following is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
<title>IT Equipments Trade-In</title>
<link href="http://new.spruceit.net/tradein/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://new.spruceit.net/tradein/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://new.spruceit.net/tradein/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://new.spruceit.net/tradein/radio.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://new.spruceit.net/tradein/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider1').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 250,
    minSlides: 2,
    maxSlides: 3,
    slideMargin: 10
  });
});
</script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#faqs">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#terms">Terms</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    <center>
    <form>
    <h1>Select Product Build Type</h1>
        <div class="cc-selector">
            <div class="slider1">                       
                        <div class="slide"><input id="WN" type="radio" name="trade-in" value="WN" />
                    <label class="drinkcard-cc WN" for="WN"></label></div>
                    <div class="slide"><input id="WD" type="radio" name="trade-in" value="WD" />
                    <label class="drinkcard-cc WD" for="WD"></label></div>
                    <div class="slide"><input id="AN" type="radio" name="trade-in" value="AN" />
                    <label class="drinkcard-cc AN" for="AN"></label></div>
                    <div class="slide"><input id="AD" type="radio" name="trade-in" value="AD" />
                    <label class="drinkcard-cc AD" for="AD"></label></div>
                    <div class="slide"><input id="WT" type="radio" name="trade-in" value="WT" />
                    <label class="drinkcard-cc WT" for="WT"></label></div>
                    <div class="slide"><input id="AT" type="radio" name="trade-in" value="AT" />
                    <label class="drinkcard-cc AT" for="AT"></label></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="xbox" class="WN box">Build type You have selected is <strong>Under Construction</strong></div>
        <div id="xbox" class="WD box">Build type You have selected is <strong>Under Construction</strong></div>
        <div id="xbox" class="AN box">Build type You have selected is <strong>Under Construction</strong></div>
        <div id="xbox" class="AD box">Build type You have selected is <strong>Under Construction</strong></div>
        <div id="xbox" class="WT box">Build type You have selected is <strong>Under Construction</strong></div>
        <div id="xbox" class="AT box">Build type You have selected is <strong>Under Construction</strong></div>
    </center></form>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2015 Trade-in Program<p>
    </div>
</body>



</html>
```

If I change the placement of scripts, all the options start to work but shows up in vertical, which is not needed.

Also, if I can add a feature in it like when the selection is made page automatically scrolls down to the form...

Comment: before anything else, you have jquery included twice. remove one of them.

Comment: Thanks alot for prompt response, kindly let me which one to remove

Comment: i would keep the one from spruceit, since you are using more scripts from the same source.

Comment: Removed but still no success !!!

Comment: i think it might be a bug with bxslider. it seems that rather than first 3 working and rest dont, actually what happens is that all groups are working except the last one. if you change max slides to 2, you will have 3 groups. the first 2 groups will work and the last one wont. if you change min and max slides to 1, you will have 6 groups. the first 5 will work, and the last one wont.

Comment: yup you are right there is bug with bxslider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>IT Equipments Trade-In</title>
    <link href="http://new.spruceit.net/tradein/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://new.spruceit.net/tradein/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://new.spruceit.net/tradein/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://new.spruceit.net/tradein/radio.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://new.spruceit.net/tradein/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('.slider1').bxSlider({
                slideWidth: 250,
                minSlides: 2,
                maxSlides: 3,
                slideMargin: 10
            });
$("label").on("click", function()
        {
            $("label").attr("style", "");
            $(this).css({
                '-webkit-filter': 'none',
                '-moz-filter'   : 'none',
                'filter'        : 'none'
            });
        });
            $('input[type="radio"]').click(function()
            {
                alert(this.value)
                if($(this).attr("value") == "WN")
                {
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".WN").show();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value") == "WD")
                {
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".WD").show();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value") == "AN")
                {
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".AN").show();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value") == "AD")
                {
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".AD").show();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value") == "WT")
                {
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".WT").show();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value") == "AT")
                {
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".AT").show();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#faqs">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#terms">Terms</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<center>
    <form>
        <h1>Select Product Build Type</h1>
        <div class="cc-selector">
            <div class="slider1">
                <div class="slide"><input id="WN" type="radio" name="trade-in" value="WN"/>
                    <label class="drinkcard-cc WN" for="WN"></label></div>
                <div class="slide"><input id="WD" type="radio" name="trade-in" value="WD"/>
                    <label class="drinkcard-cc WD" for="WD"></label></div>
                <div class="slide"><input id="AN" type="radio" name="trade-in" value="AN"/>
                    <label class="drinkcard-cc AN" for="AN"></label></div>
                <div class="slide"><input id="AD" type="radio" name="trade-in" value="AD"/>
                    <label class="drinkcard-cc AD" for="AD"></label></div>
                <div class="slide"><input id="WT" type="radio" name="trade-in" value="WT"/>
                    <label class="drinkcard-cc WT" for="WT"></label></div>
                <div class="slide"><input id="AT" type="radio" name="trade-in" value="AT"/>
                    <label class="drinkcard-cc AT" for="AT"></label></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="xbox" class="WN box">Build type You have selected is <strong>WN Under Construction</strong></div>
        <div id="xbox" class="WD box">Build type You have selected is <strong>WD Under Construction</strong></div>
        <div id="xbox" class="AN box">Build type You have selected is <strong>AN Under Construction</strong></div>
        <div id="xbox" class="AD box">Build type You have selected is <strong>AD Under Construction</strong></div>
        <div id="xbox" class="WT box">Build type You have selected is <strong>WT Under Construction</strong></div>
        <div id="xbox" class="AT box">Build type You have selected is <strong>AT Under Construction</strong></div>
    </form>
</center>
<div id="footer">
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2015 Trade-in Program
    <p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this works perfectly but the first three option when selected they show that option is selected by converting them into color, but other three dont show up selected even when selected but showing the box correctly

Comment: Yup now its working, thanks alot.

one more feature I need is, that when clicked on any of option page automatically scrolls down to show form !!

Answer (score 0):

i did the animate scroll by adding following:

$('#xbox').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:3000,easing:'easeOutBounce'});

now my script looks like:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function()
            {
                if($(this).attr("value") == "WN")
                {
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".WN").show();
                    $('#xbox').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:3000,easing:'easeOutBounce'});
                }
                if($(this).attr("value") == "WD")
                {
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".WD").show();
                    $('#xbox1').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:3000,easing:'easeOutBounce'});
                }
                if($(this).attr("value") == "AN")
                {
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".AN").show();
                    $('#xbox2').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:3000,easing:'easeOutBounce'});
                }
                if($(this).attr("value") == "AD")
                {
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".AD").show();
                    $('#xbox3').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:3000,easing:'easeOutBounce'});
                }
                if($(this).attr("value") == "WT")
                {
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".WT").show();
                    $('#xbox4').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:3000,easing:'easeOutBounce'});
                }
                if($(this).attr("value") == "AT")
                {
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".AT").show();
                    $('#xbox5').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:3000,easing:'easeOutElastic'});
                }
            });
        });
```